# Firebase recyclerview not refreshing

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

I am trying to refresh my RecyclerView based on data from a new query after reading data from the Firebase database. When the app is first opened, the recyclerview is populated with items based on an initial query and it is supposed to refresh with a new query immediately afterwards.However, the data is not been refreshed after data from the first query has been displayed.Am i doing anything wrong? Please help

```
users2 = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.users_list);
    users2.setHasFixedSize(false);
    users2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

    query = databaseReference;

     final FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<User, UserViewholder>(
            User.class, R.layout.users_row, UserViewholder.class, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(UserViewholder viewHolder, User model, int position) {
            viewHolder.setUsername(model.getUsername());
            viewHolder.setLevels(model.getLevels());
            viewHolder.setDownloadUrl(getApplicationContext(), model.getDownloadUrl());
        }

    };

    users2.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    final String user_id = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

            halls2 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Male").child(user_id).child("halls").getValue();
            halls1 = (String) dataSnapshot.child("Female").child(user_id).child("halls").getValue();



        }
        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });

    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){


            if(dataSnapshot.child("Male").hasChild(user_id)){

                 query = databaseReference.child("Female").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls2);

            }
            else{
                query = databaseReference.child("Male").orderByChild("halls").equalTo(halls1);

            }
            firebaseRecyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }

        @Override
        public  void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError){

        }
    });
```

Comment: This is exactly same question like the one you post before (which is now removed). Did you delete the old one?

Comment: I changed the users2.setHasFixedSize to FALSE but it still didnt work @koceeng

Comment: apart from that, did you remove old question and make this new question to avoid downvote or to bump your question to the top list?